# Jquery executing function after multiple images have been fetched from dropbox

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, promise, filereader, jquery-deferred

My goal: create click-handlers for multiple images that are dynamically created inside an bootstrapped popup-menu after a button was clicked inside that same popup-menu

My problem: the images are asynchronously fetched from dropbox with an each-loop . My code to bind  click-handlers to those images executes before the async operations completes.(So the images aren't appended to the dom yet). I am trying to use JQueries deferred/promises but can't find any examples that suits my needs.

```
//client = dropbox-client
client.readdir("/" + album, function (error, entries)
{
    if (error) {
        return showError(error); // Something went wrong.
    }

    function createBlobs()
    {

        //console.log("createBlobs(); entries are: " + entries);
        var deferreds = [];
        $.each(entries, function (index, value)
        {

            //get the file from dropbox
            client.readFile("/" + album + "/" + value, {blob: true}, function (error, data)
            {
                if (error) {
                    return handleError(error);
                }
                deferreds.push(
                        showBlob(data, value));

                function showBlob(blob, value)
                {
                    console.log("showblob()...: creating img template for value: " + value);
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    var defer = $.Deferred();
                    reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                        return function (e) {
                            var l = "<li class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12' style='list-style:none; margin-bottom:25px'>\n\
                                    <img src='" + e.target.result + "' width='100%' style='border:5px solid green' \n\
                                        id='bbblob_album_" + album + "_img_" + value + "'></img></li>";
                            list.append(l);
                            defer.resolve();
                        };
                    })(blob);

                    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                    return defer.promise();
                }
                ;
            });
        });
        return deferreds;
    }

    var dDone = createBlobs();

    console.log("createBlobs(): returned promise , should now go and implementing clickhandlers");
    $.when.apply(null, dDone).done(function () {
        console.log("showBlob executed for each entry; now executing ladieda()");
        ladieda();
    });

});


function ladieda()
{
    console.log("ladieda()");
    $('.d > ul').children('li').each(function () {
        console.log("inside each (li) of ladieda");
        //alert(this.id); // "this" is the current element in the loop
        $(this).children('img').each(function () {
           //alert(this.id); // "this" is the current element in the loop
            $(this).on('click', function () {
               alert("clicked " + this.id); // "this" is the current element in the loop

            });
        });
    });
}
```

SOLUTION (thanks to wolf)

```
list.on( "click", "li > img", function( event ) {
    var elem = $( this );

    if ( elem.is( "[id^='bbblob_album_"+album+"_img_"+value+"']" ) ) {
        //elem.attr( "target", "_blank" );
        alert("clicked " + this.id); // "this" is the current element in the loop

    }
});
```

Comment: You should delegate click event instead: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I have updated my question with the function ladieda; Ideally i want to execute ladieda inside of the reader.onload method, but then i get multiple alerts when i click on one image.

Comment: but you should delegate event, e.g: `list.on('click', 'img', handler);` Read link posted above